# Was there a church around 1800 in Petropavlovsk-Kamchatsky?

Tags: russia, colonization, church, kamchatka

Petropavlovsk-Kamchatsky, founded in 1742, had just 85 residents in 1792. According to "So Far From Home" (Farris, ed.), a priest named Yakov Volkov was there in the 1790s. Was there a church? Because the Kamchatka diocese was not created until around 1840, was it in the Irkutsk diocese?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [I. V. Viter](http://www.kamlib.ru/resourses/petropavlovsk.htm), in 1767 the town population couldn't support the church, so it was moved to nearby Paratunka.

According to [Svetlana G. Federova and her coauthor Yakov M. Svet](http://library.alaska.gov/hist/hist_docs/docs/anlm/02057447.pdf), Captain Charles Clerke was buried in 1779 "on the high northern shore of the Petropavlovsk harbor near a new church that was being built".

According to A. Sgibnev, quoted in E. A. P. Crownhart-Vaughan's "Clerke in Kamchatka, 1779", in that year, "the church was in ruins".

According to Viter again, in 1800 the previously removed church returned from Paratunka, whose residents had all died in an epidemic, probably Typhus.

According to [G. Langsdorff](https://archive.org/stream/voyagesandtrave00langgoog#page/n178/mode/2up/search/petropavlovsk), writing in about 1804, "here live[s] ... a clergyman, though there is no church."

According to the "[Kamchatka Museum of Local Lore](http://poluostrov-k-ru.1gb.ru/park/muzey/120_2.htm)", in 1810 a new town church was consecrated, and in 1814 another chapel was added.

All this took place in the Irkutsk diocese where the bishop from 1789 to 1814 was Beniamin Bagrianski.